# pyqtgraph exporting from API within PyQt4 widget fails / crashes python

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a small application that I have built using PyQt4 and pyqtgraph. I want to put a few buttons in that call the exporters available with pyqtgraph (rather than, or really in addition to, using the context menu that pops up when a user right clicks on a plot).

So far, however, I have not been able to get this to work.

Here is a simplified version of the application:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import numpy as np
import sys


class SimpleUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.resize(1500, 1000)
        self.plot_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        data = np.arange(10)
        self.plt = self.plot_widget.addPlot()
        self.plt.plot(data)

        self.export_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Export")
        self.export_btn.clicked.connect(self.export)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.export_btn)

    def export(self):
        img = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(self.plt)
        img.export()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SimpleUi()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Clicking on the "Export" button in this case causes a dialog to quickly pop up and then disappear.

If instead I put

```
img.export(copy=True)
```

And try to paste what's on the clipboard into something (Paint, whatever), python.exe crashes.

Oddly, exporting through the context menu that is available by default with pyqtgraph works just fine. Also, just working in the terminal I can copy / save plotItems just fine using the same exact lines of code as above. I.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters

plt = pg.plot(np.arange(10))
img = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(plt.plotItem)
img.export()
```

Which implies to me that that exporters are working fine, but there is some weird interaction that is going on when they are called from within a pyqt4 widget in the manner that I am calling them.

I have tried both pyqtgraph 0.9.8 as well as the main branch on github. Very much at a loss as to what is the issue here

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not storing `img` anywhere, so it is collected as soon as the call to `export()` returns.

Explanation:

1. Objects in Python are kept in memory only as long as they are needed. When Python determines that an object is no longer needed, it deletes the object.
2. How does Python know when an object is no longer needed? By counting references. When you execute `img = ImageExporter(...)`, a new object is created with one reference: the local variable `img`.
3. Variables that are created inside a function are considered local to the scope of that function. When the function exits, the variable `img` disappears, which causes the reference count of the `ImageExporter` object to drop to 0, which causes Python to delete the object.
4. By setting `self.img = ImageExporter(...)`, you are assigning a reference to the object that is *not* local to the scope of the function (because the `SimpleUI` object referred to as `self` continues to exist after the function returns). This allows the object to persist as long as the `SimpleUI` still holds the reference.

Comment: So changing img to an instance variable (i.e. self.img) fixes the problem. It's unclear to me why, though. I'm sure this is a relatively basic cs question, but would you mind explaining what's going on? For example, if I add print(img) to the export function I get an exporter object at a memory location. Why since img.export() is being called within the same function is that object not saved / used?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought I had a decent understanding of all of that, but I guess not. I assume, then, that by calling img.export() we are leaving the scope of my export function, which is why the img object is lost?

Comment: No, calling `img.export()` only opens the file dialog and then returns immediately, at which point `SimpleUI.export()` also returns and `img` is deleted.

Comment: I understand that img is lost once SimpleUI.export() returns. What I'm having trouble understanding is why that matters. The purpose of img.export() is to generate a file from img (or add a png to the clipboard), correct? That action is completed when img.export() returns, is it not? Which is why I'm not clear on why img needs to persist beyond the completion of SimpleUI.export(). Sorry if what's going on should be obvious, but thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: when I say "generate a file from img" I mean from the plotItem that is passed when the img instance of ImageExporter class is created

Comment: Calling `img.export()` displays the file dialog and returns immediately. The actual export does not take place until after the user decides on a file name and presses "save", at which point `img` has already been deleted.